# How do I ask the user for input to remove any row from linked list ? (Using get and set methods)

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a code that asks the user for input to remove any of the rows from my input file that I stored to my lined list index. Furthermore I will also have an error exception if the user went out of bounds or the row does not exist/not in the range.

I need to use a get method to get my index and return it and then use the remove method.  At the end, I will output the file with the added changes and show it to the user.
I don't know if I my my get and remove methods are correct.
Hopefully someone can point me to the right direction !

here is my code thus far:

```css
//class JOptionPane
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//class String Tokenizer
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
//class Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
//class File
import java.io.File;
//class FileNotFoundException
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Testing19{
 
   public static void main(String[]args){
    //checks to see if there's an input file in the commandline
      if(args.length != 1) 
       //displays an error if there's none
         System.out.println("ERROR: NO INPUT FOUND");
      else{
       //create a new object file from the commandline
         File file = new File(args[0]);
       //creat a new scanner
         Scanner data = null;
         try{
          //creates a link between the file and data
            data = new Scanner(file);
         
         }
         catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          //displays the error
            System.out.println("ERROR: File not found");
         }
       //initialize a string for the 
         String output = new String();
       //this will check for data inside the file
         while(data.hasNextLine()){
          //read the data per line in the file
            String line = data.nextLine();
          //initialize a string for name
            String name;
          //initialize a string for age
            String scientificname;
            //initialize a string for age
            String color;
            //initialize a string for age
            String population; 
          //make a new scanner for token
            Scanner tokenInput = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");
          //assign the first token as a string
            name = tokenInput.next();
            //assign the first token as a string
            scientificname = tokenInput.next();
            //assign the first token as a string
            color = tokenInput.next();
          //assign the second token as an string
            population = tokenInput.next();
          //reads the 2nd token as an integer
            Integer population2 = Integer.parseInt(population);
          //create a new object list from the class LinkedList
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
          //calls the add() method from the LinkedList class
            list.add(name, scientificname, color, population2);
          //assign the result in the output string
            output = output + list;
         }
        //displays the output in the JOption pane
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
       
      }
    
   }//end of main
}//end of class

/****************************************
* Class LinkedList
*
*****************************************/
class LinkedListAldz{
 //datafield
   protected HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode head = null;
   protected Integer size = new Integer(0);
 //add()method
   public void add(String name2, String scientificname2, String color2, Integer population2){
      if (head == null) {
       //new PersonNode and store it on head if the list is empty
         head = new HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode(name2,scientificname2,color2,population2, null);
      }
      else {
       //adds to the end of the list
         HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode previous = head;
         HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode current = head.getNext();
         while (current != null) {
          //next PersonNode
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
         }
       //new PersonNode at the of the list.
         HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode birds = new HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode(name2,scientificname2,color2,population2,null);
       //point previous node
         previous.setNext(birds);
      }
      size++;
   }
   
   /**
  * Gets an item (address to an item) from any position in the list.
  * 
  * @param position
  *            The position of an item in the list.
  * @returns the address to the requested item
  * @exception ListException
  *                if an item does not exist at that position
  */
   public int get(Integer position)  {
    // check if empty list
      if (head == null) {
         System.out.println("Cannot get an item from an empty list!");
      }
    // if position is outside range, throw exception
      if (position < 1 || position > size) {
         System.out.println(position + " is outside list range!");
      }
    // Find node:
    // counter to keep track of loops
      Integer counter = new Integer(1);
    // point to current node
      HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode current = head;
      while (!counter.equals(position)) {
       // BAD CODE: while(counter != position){
       // goto next node for current pointer
         current = current.getNext();
       // add 1 to counter
         counter++;
      }
    // return the data (item) stored by the node
      return current.getData();
      
   }
   
   /**
  * Removes an item at any position from the list.
  * 
  * @param position
  *            The position of an item in the list.
  * @exception ListException
  *                if an item does not exist at that position
  */
   public void remove(Integer position) throws ListException {
    // check if empty list
      if (head == null) {
         throw new ListException("cannot remove from empty list");
      }
    // if position is outside range, throw exception
      if (position < 1 || position > size) {
         throw new ListException(position + " is outside list range.");
      }
    // if at beginning of list
      if (position.equals(1)) {
       // remove 1st node
         head = head.getNext();
      }
      // if not at beginning of list
      else {
       // Find node:
       // point previous to 1st node
         HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode previous = head;
       // point current to 2nd node
         HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode
            current = head.getNext();
       // loop position-2 number of times
         for (int i = 2; i < position; i++) {
          // goto next node for previous and current
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
         }
       // Point the previous node to node after current node.
       // This "skips" over one node, thus removing it!
         previous.setNext(current.getNext());
      }
    // decrease size of list
      size--;
   }
   
   
  //toString()method
   public String toString() {
    // instantiate empty string
      String csvFormat = new String("");
    // display position of each item to user
      Integer position = new Integer(1);
    // loop through all the nodes in linked list
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode current = head; current != null; current = current
        .getNext()) {
       // keep adding to end of string
         csvFormat = csvFormat + current.toString() + "\n";
       // add one to position for each loop
         position++;
      }
      return csvFormat;
   }
   
   
}//end of LinkedList


/****************************************
* Class PersonNode 
* @ param name for the name
*    age  for the age
*    next for the next PersonNode
*****************************************/
   

 class HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode{
     //data fields are set to private
       private String name;
       private String scientificname;
       private String color;
       private Integer population;
       private HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode next;
     
     /********************************
     * constructor method
     * @ param x is for the name
     *    y is for the age
     *    next2 is for the next
     ********************************/
       public HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode(String x, String y, String z, Integer b, HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode next2) {
          name = x;
          scientificname = y;
          color = z;
          population = b;
          next = next2;
       }
     
     /*******************************
     * calls the toString method
     * from the class String
     * returns result
     ********************************/
       public String toString(){
        //initialize te format of the output 
          String result =  name + "    "+  scientificname + "    " +  color  + "    "+  population;
          return result;
       }
     
     /*********************
     * acessory method
     * returns name
     **********************/
       public String getName(){
          return name;
       }
       
       /*********************
     * acessory method
     * returns name
     **********************/
       public String getScientificname(){
          return scientificname;
       }
          
          /*********************
     * acessory method
     * returns name
     **********************/
       public String getColor(){
          return color;
       }

     
     /*********************
     * acessory method
     * returns age
     **********************/
       public Integer getPopulation(){
          return population;
       }
     /*********************
     * acessory method
     * returns next
     **********************/
       public HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode getNext(){
          return next;
       }
     
     /*********************
     * mutator method
     * @ param x is set name
     **********************/
       public void setName(String x){
          name = x;
       }
       
       
     /*********************
     * mutator method
     * @ param x is set name
     **********************/
       public void setScientificName(String y){
          scientificname = y;
       }
       
       
     /*********************
     * mutator method
     * @ param x is set name
     **********************/
       public void setColor(String z){
          color = z;
       }


     
     /*********************
     * mutator method
     * @ param y is set age
     **********************/
       public void setPopulation(Integer b){
          population = b;
       }
     
     /**************************
     * nutator method
     * @ param next2 is set next
     ***************************/
       public void setNext(HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode next2){
          next = next2;
       }
    }//end of HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode
```

The format of my input file is as follows:

```css
1.akiapola'au,hemignathus munroi,yellow,800
2.akepa,loxops coccineus,red,9301
3.hawai'i creeper,oreomystis mana,yellow green,2501
4.i'iwi,vestiara coccinea,red green,30001
5.apapane,himatione sanguinea,white red,5001
6.hawai'i amakihi,hemignathus virens,yellow brown,3001
7.oma'o,myadestes obscurus,gray,170001
8.hawai'an hawk,buteo solitarius,white gray,1100
9.puaiohi,myadestes palmeri,brown,125
10.anianiau,magumma parva,light yellow,2000
```

I tried running it and I get an error:

```css
Testing19.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
      return current.getData();
                    ^
  symbol:   method getData()
  location: variable current of type HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode
1 error
```

Comment: General comment: The Java collections expose a class called `LinkedList`, so you might want to name yours something else, e.g. `LinkedListAldz`

Comment: Even more general comment: please read [MCVE] guidance on providing code in posts.

Comment: will change the linkedlist now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your class 'HawaiiNativeForestBirdsNode' does not contain a method 'getData ()'. That's why the exception is thrown. To get the users input you should use a BufferedReader instead:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = br.readLine();
```

- Luis

Comment: so which part of my code should I replace? the get or the remove method?

Comment: oh just replace my remove method with that lemme try

Comment: oh man... still getting errors on my getData section, How Do I fix that so it would not show an error, and I inputstreamerReader is giving me an error